# Kafka JDBC sink connector causing high (99%) CPU usages

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka JDBC Sink connector to pull data from kafka topics into MariaDB. One of my kafka sink connector causing high(99%) CPU usages in production server. But other sink connectors are working fine. My initial observation is that this particular kafka sink connector has two topics but (12*2) 24 partitions causing this issue (while other connectors consist topics having 1/2 partions). Is there any way to deal with this case?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Environment:
Kafka Version: 5.4.2-ccs,
Brocker: 3,
Schema Registry: 3,
Zookeeper: 3

Kafka Connect Worker Config:

[image]

Java Process:

[image]

Comment: What is tasks.max for the connector? How many connect workers?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Initially it was 2. Later changed to 32. But observed no improvement.

Comment: Added config file and CPU usage. Found One active java process using top.

Comment: So, only one machine running connect-standalone? Why not more than one connect server?

Comment: Yes. We are using connect-standalone. Primarily we did not need one. In future if we need to use distributed connect we may use multiple machine. Is there any particular necessity to use distributed connect with the increase of partitions? We only have 2 topics with (12*2) partitions. Other topics have one partition each.

Comment: Well, I don't know how many cpu threads your server can handle, but is it anywhere near 24? If not, you should be using more than one server for optimal performance. Besides, standalone mode isn't exactly meant for production use as it's not fault tolerant

Comment: Issue Solved. Possibly our infra team may have changed something that I am not aware of. Anyway thanks a lot @OneCricketeer.  I will recommend my senior to use kafka connect in distributed mode.